# $http Post to php backend, but the server side gets nothing

Tags: angularjs, http-post

I'm learning AngularJS, and trying to post dump data to the php backend using the coding below.

```
angular.module('app.customerModule', [])
    .factory('customerFactory', function($scope, $http) {
        return {
            var customer = {customer: '1234'};
            httpNewCustomer: function(callback) {
                $http.post('http://domain.local/customer_new.php', )
                  .success(function(data) {
            })
        }
    }
})
.controller('customerController', function($rootScope, $scope, customerFactory) {
    $scope.newCustomer = function() {       
        customerFactory.httpNewCustomer(function(dataResponse) {
        });
    }
});
```

Unfortunately at the server side gets nothing for $_POST;

This is what the http header looks like.

[image]

I also tried with this alternative coding

```
httpNewCustomers: function(callback) {
    var postData = {customer: '2345'};

    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'http://domain.local/customer_new.php',
        data: postData,
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=utf-8'}
    })
        .success(function(data) {
        })
}
```

This is what the http header looks like.

[image]

When I tried with jQuery using this coding, everything is just fine.

```
var postData = {customer: '3456'};

$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
url: 'http://domain.local/customer_new.php',
dataType: 'json',
data: postData,
success: function(data) {
    // console.log(data);
}
});
```

[image]

Please help me config the $http to post the data to the php backend.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

angular by default only supports a json request transformer. as you can see, both your angular requests have data, but they are json. You either need to change the server so it can parse json, or add a request transformer so the data is in form-encoded format.

You can read more about $http transformers here: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http